# Batch file, script or shortcut to delete the most recent file in a specified folder

Tags: windows, windows-8, script, batch-file

anyone know how to make a batch file or script or some other simple thing like a shortcut that calls some exe to do the following:

I want to click on something (batch file, script or shortcut) that will delete the last file in a specified folder.. only the last (most recent) file.

Why would I want to do this?

Sometimes I accidentally take a "wrong" screenshot. I would like to be able to delete it quickly.

Comment: maybe someone knows how to translate something in here into a batch file to do that? http://superuser.com/questions/123347/windows-batch-scripting-newest-file-matching-a-pattern

Comment: Last one, based on what? Name? Sort order? Modified Date? Creation date? Is it sorted ascending or descending? You need some more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch file:

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\yourPath"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do (
  del "%%F"
  exit /b
)
```

Command line (no batch script) that could be included directly in a shortcut.

```
cmd /c pushd "c:\yourPath"&for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do @(del "%F"&exit)"
```

Comment: thanks, decided to go with the batch file. At first it didn't work, some strange error about no thumbs.db found. So I put a *.png after dir and then it worked great!

Comment: would you know of a way to delete the file to the recycle bin?

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell:

```
dir C:\YourPath | sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -desc | select -First 1 | del
```

Or calling PowerShell from a batch script:

```
PowerShell -ep unrestricted -Command "dir C:\YourPath | sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -desc | select -First 1 | del"
```

As protection against accidentally calling it more than once (if you don't do screenhosts too often) you can limit the age of the deleted file to e. g. 10 minutes by adding this before the `| del` :

```
| where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddMinutes(-10)}
```